# how to get auto.arima(trace=True) as a object in python?

Tags: python, arima

I searched for the solution, I found a solution in r programming, I need a solution in python, thank you.

using this code

```
model=auto_arima(test_series_df_1,trace=True,stepwise=True,error_action='ignore')
```

[image]
I need to capture this trace output to get the second-best arima model.